# "‘People for whom gold holds no allure"

Tags: sentence-structure

[Oxford dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/allure) gives an example for using of the word "**allure**":

> ‘People **for whom gold** holds no allure’

I read it again and again and I'm not sure I understood it and I'm afraid something here is wrong or it's a kind of a complicated  structure of a sentence and then I'd like to know what kind of structure it is, then I'll read and learn about it.

Answer (score 4):

"People for whom gold holds no allure" isn't actually a full sentence, but a noun phrase. Like a noun, a noun phrase can serve as *part* of a sentence, such as a subject or a direct object.

For example, suppose I know or have heard of some **people**, and one of the things I know about these **people** is that **gold holds no allure for them**. (That is, they don't find gold very interesting or enticing.) Now suppose I find that very surprising and hard to understand, perhaps because gold holds a great deal of allure for me. I can express this by using the noun phrase **people for whom gold holds no allure** as a direct object:

I simply can't understand **people for whom gold holds no allure**.

Or I can express more or less the same idea by using the noun phrase as the subject of a sentence:

**People for whom gold holds no allure** completely mystify me.